# asp.net membership system

Tags: asp.net, authentication, azure

I'm building an asp.net application that will later be ported to azure.

For the moment, I have  all the business tables in one database and a separate database that I use for membership; it's basically the default database that the login control generates.

In the business database, I have a table that contains user profile data and one field is TheUserID (which is an int) and another field that's called TheUserMembership (a string), which will contain the user ID that's generated by the asp.net user management tool.

Once the user logs in, I store TheUserID in the session and the whole app works with the int as the identifier.

Is this a good way to do it? Will this port to azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx

And then yes it will port to Azure and SQL Azure.

**Things to watch out for with Azure**

Local storage (disk storage). Since you have multiple instances, local storage doesn't work as you will never be able to tell which instance it is on.

Session state must be out of proc, for the same reason as above.

There are many other little things here or there about Azure but those would be the 2 biggest to watch out for when moving across.

Comment: If you wanted to find out any more specific information, please elaborate further on your question. And is there any reason your user data and business data is in a seperate database?

Comment: Ok, then it will port over to Azure well. Just updated my answer with a few things.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of InProc session limitations; I plan on using AppFabric to store the sessions.

Answer (score 0):

the user id is a GUID and it you can find the on the users table, you should not store user id into session since cookie can be stolen. for azure one principal requirement is that all tables have a primary key